# How to make animation for app icon in android?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-icons

I see that on **iOS** icon app (screen icon) clock application have clockwise movement.

How do I do it in Android?

Comment: Search on _Google_ first

Comment: A search tool that can aid in the answering of your question

Comment: And what is stackoverflow ?

Comment: Take a look [How to ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Before I raise a question to here I find it use google, so that pls help me instead of down vote or recomment to a search to general tool. Thanks for your understand

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in another way, i.e,

Create a launcher animation `Activity` and set the `windowsManager`'s `LayoutParam` to get the desired bounds. Also, you can change the launcher `Activity` theme to ```Dialog````` theme, then you can see the change.

Comment: Hi @VYSHAK M, thanks for your answer. But here i want to make screen icon app that can be show as a gif picture ( not static as you usually in android app). I only see Clock application on ios can be do that.